Is $(Fr_O(V) \times GL(n))/O(n) \cong Fr(V)$?
Take a vector bundle $V$ of rank $n$ over a manifold. The orthonormal frame bundle $Fr_O(V)$ of $V$ may be constructed as a reduction of the structure group $GL(n)$ of the frame bundle $Fr(V)$ of $V$ along the canonical inclusion $\rho: O(n) \hookrightarrow GL(n)$.
Conversely, we ought to be able to recover $Fr(V)$ (up to isomorphism) from the orthonormal $Fr_O(V)$ using what is sometimes referred to as the "extension" of its structure group $O(n)$, via the associated principal $GL(n)$-bundle $Fr_O(V)_{\rho}$,
$$Fr_O(V)_{\rho} := (Fr_O(V) \times GL(n))/O(n)$$
where we are quotienting along the diagonal action, $(f, m) \sim (f.g,\rho(g)^{-1}m), f \in Fr_O(V), m \in GL(n), g \in O(n)$
Without resorting to any bundle arguments, how may I see that $(Fr_O(V) \times GL(n))/O(n) \cong Fr(V)$?

What have you tried?:)

@BobDobbs Constructing the quotient space by hand, albeit I do not see any obvious isomorphisms.

It might help to generalise: your question is a special case of the following construction. Suppose $\pi_P:P\to M$ is a principal $G$-bundle, $H\subset G$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $\pi_Q:Q\to M$ is a reduction of $P$ to $H$, i.e. a principal $H$-bundle with an injective map $I:Q\to P$ that is $H$-equivariant (i.e. $I(q\cdot h) = I(q)\cdot h$ for all $q\in Q, h\in H$) and that covers the identity on $M$ (i.e. $\pi_P\circ I = \pi_Q$). (Note that injectivity of $I$ is required for the $H$-equivariance to make sense.) Then as principal $G$-bundles
$$
Q\times_H G \simeq P
$$
via the map $\Psi([q,g]_H) := I(q)\cdot g$. In order to prove that $\Psi$ is a bundle isomorphism, you need to show that

$\Psi$ is well-defined
$\Psi$ is surjective
$\Psi$ is injective
$\Psi$ is $G$-equivariant

All four are straightforward to prove, though possible the third is slightly less trivial.
Your question is just the special case that $P = Fr(V)$, $Q=Fr_O(V)$, $G=GL(n)$, and $H=O(n)$.

Thank you for the response, but how might I have deduced the isomorphism? In my example, it does not seem obvious to me that "translating" the frame of a fibre over a point by a chosen $GL(n)$ element is equivalently kept track of through $[q,g]_H$ (using your notation).

Not sure what to say apart from that you might have guessed because it's the only possible construction you could make in this circumstance. If you're thinking of $Q$ as a subset of $P$, then the isomorphism is simply $[q,g]_H\mapsto q\cdot g$, and this doesn't depend on the particular representative of the equivalence class, since $(q\cdot h)\cdot (h^{-1}g) = q\cdot g$ - this is the "well-definedness" I refer to above.

I'm inclined to ask how you are confident there is no other construction, but I will ask instead if you have any words that might make it more intuitive what $(q,g) \mapsto [q, g]_H$ is functionally doing in my example. The point is that the orthonormal frames are taken to all frames by that quotienting magic, but I do not explicitly see how (except in general terms of extension of structure group).

Another way to think of it: the map $\Phi:Q\times G \to P$ given by $\Phi(q,g):=q\cdot g$ is surjective, i.e. you can map an orthogonal frame to an arbitrary frame via an element of $GL(n)$. Now which pairs $(q',g')\in Q\times G$ map to the same element $q\cdot g$ of $P$? Precisely those in $\lbrace (q\cdot h, h^{-1}g) \mid h\in H\rbrace$, i.e. frames where you post-multiply $q$ by an orthogonal matrix, and pre-multiply $g$ by its inverse. But this is the equivalence class of $(q,g)$ (and motivates the relation). So $\Phi:Q\times G\to P$ induces a bijection $\Psi:Q\times_H G\to P$.

Thank you for expanding. I had a related question about oriented, orthonormal frames $Fr^+_O(V)$ here, which is one step further in reductions of the structure group. I would like to understand how we can view the same story in terms of classifying spaces rather than explicit vector bundles (by way of the simple example there). May I ask if you have any insight there?

I don't, sorry.
